# How can I enable the Box (or Block) Selection in Eclipse IDE?

Tags: visual-studio, eclipse, ide, comparison

I have been using `Visual Studio IDE` and I use [`Box Selection`](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vseditor/archive/2009/05/25/the-new-box-selection-now-with-multi-line-editing.aspx) a lot.
Is the same possible for `Eclipse IDE`?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Since Eclipse 3.5 there is a button called `Block selection mode` in the main toolbar or you could use its hotkey as well:

- Windows: <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>
- Mac: <kbd>Command</kbd>+<kbd>Option</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>

See [a blog entry about block selection](http://www.vasanth.in/2009/03/31/eclipse-tip-block-selection-mode/) for more details.

Comment: Is it also possible to show the icon in other Eclipse editors (i.e. php editor)? When I open a PHP file it is possible to activate block selection with the shortcut but the icon disappears from the toolbar.

Answer (score 0):

youtube walkthrough: [How to enable block selection in eclipse](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DnVSHglcZB0) and you'll be done in 2 minutes.

also explains how to setup custom hotkey, if **Alt+Shft+A** is already taken